# Recover All Files On Lost Partition

Tags: partition, partition-table, forensics, testdisk

I had a sdd with two partitions on it. The first was 32G and the second took up the remainder of the drive. The first was the root partition with Ubuntu installed on it. The second was a general storage area.

I accidentally pointed dd at this sdd with this command:

```
dd if=/2g-ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sda
```

Because less than 3G of contiguous data were written at the beginning of the physical disk this overwrite never made it to the second partition. So I immeadiealy unmounted the drive and have only mounted it in read mode since. Nothing was written over the second partition inodes and zones, so those files are untouched.

testdisk tells me the superblock is damaged.

I've tried reading all backup superblocks but those are damaged as well.

So it looks like I have to rely on reading inodes and their corresponding zone data to recover files.

Is there a program that I point to that portion of the disk and gather all files?  I've looked at testdisk but it seems to only look for file types but I need it find every file without discretion.

**TROUBLESHOOTING - Finding the lost partition with dd**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

count = 0

skip32Gigs = 0

while 1:

    dd_args = ["dd", "if=/dev/sda", "bs=512", "skip=" + str(skip32Gigs+count), "count=4"]
    file_args = ['file', "-"]
    print 'dd_args', dd_args

    dd_process = Popen(dd_args, stdout=PIPE)
    file_process = Popen(file_args, stdin=dd_process.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    dd_process.stdout.close()
    out, err = file_process.communicate()

    print out.split(), err

    if "Linux" in out.split():
        break

    count += 1
```

xxx

Comment: According to what you wrote, you'd just have to restore the correct partition definition and get the 2nd partition and  its filesystem working fine. So it's all about finding the start of the partition and its size (which you can make arbitrarily large, as long as it's larger than the filesystem). So I'm surprised by testdisk's results. And better never use /dev/sdX directly but /dev/disk/by-*/ instead to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: Could you provide the steps one would take to restore the correct partition definition in an answer?

Comment: So, read the raw data of the drive and there should be some magic number or something like that? Do you know the size of the blocks of data I would be reading in and what data would tell me I've found an ext4 partition?

Comment: When testing, 2k= 4 x 512b sectors appears enough for the file command to detect ext4, but maybe use twice this. For example here I have `dd if=/dev/sdc bs=512 skip=206848 count=4 |file -` giving `/dev/stdin: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=a3e20c71-c2c3-4986-8585-xxxxxxxxxxxx, volume name "boot" (extents) (huge files)`. That's the start of the partition, because the filesystem is immediately at the start of the partition.

Comment: I updated the question based on your comment. I want to skip past the first 32 gigs because I know the partition is not there. What number do I put to skip? And when I do find the partition how can I figure out from this dd info where it starts exactly?

Comment: Just be conservative. skip only 30GB (30*10^9) rather than 32GiB (32*2^30). As the count is in blocks, you have to divide this by the block size. And don't assume the first hit will be the right one with only "Linux" as match.

Comment: (10^9 x 30) / (512 x 4) = 14648437.5 But how do I deal with the decimal?

Comment: really? you remove 1. or you remove 10. and you ignore the decimal. and your calculus is wrong. bs=512. not 2048. in dd bs means block size.

Comment: You must have got the concept. I leave the implementation details to you.

Comment: This is why I asked for an example, although I understand the idea their are probably several gotchas that will spawn more and more questions because I have no experience with these specific tools.